# magnifying DIV using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DIV on my page with position absolute and ID `magnify` and under this DIV there is another DIV with some auto moving/scrolling small images...

what i'm trying to do is to make the DIV magnify to act like a magnifying glass..

so as each small image goes under that DIV, it shows the image a bit bigger like a magnifying glass.

here is what I have so far but this code doesn't make the magnify div like a magnifying glass and I don't understand why!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function () {
            $('#magnify').animate({ 'zoom': 1});
        }
    });
</script>
```

could someone please advise on this?

EDIT:

This is an example of what I am referring to:

[image]

so the icons moving/scrolling under the magnifying glass/DIV... Also the Magnifying Div doesn't move. the only thing that moves is the images/icons under the magnifying glass.

Comment: maybe you can using CSS3 scale

Comment: Could you give us a fiddle ? : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Your code as it stands will cause an error due to the anonymous function not being assigned to anything.

Comment: No HTML/CSS makes it more difficult to say where it's going wrong, but for starters you don't define the mouseover. Take a look at [this](http://codepen.io/akhbar/pen/Biupr) website. It gives a working example and a lot of comments to explain the code.

Comment: @Casper, I don't define the mouse over because I don't want it to work with mouse over! I just need the DIV to act as a magnifying glass no matter if the mouse is over it, under it or no where near it.

Comment: So you want to show a picture, and in the magnify div you want to show a larger version of it? (showing the whole picture at once)

Comment: and I don't know why someone downvoted a valid question but its all good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how your slider works but what I would do is when the image you want to magnify is active/under the 'magnifying glass' then add a CSS class to it to scale it using CSS.

i.e.

```
.image { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.image-active { transform: scale(1.5); }
```

Comment: I cannot use this code because the whole images/icons are actually 1 big image.. so they are not individual images if that makes sense.

Comment: I did try that mate.. there is so much code that will confuse anyone if you try to go through it and I cannot put just a tiny bit of the code in jsfiddle as it wont work and it doesn't make sense.. but in a sense, I am trying to do exactly whats shown in the image in my Edit above.